# I have an error chen I'm trying to download ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Yesterday, I began to download Ionic however I have a problem during the installation.
I managed to install ionic and angular but it makes me an error when I try to choose a template. Whatever the template I choose, it puts me "error" (look in the photo). 
Can you help me please ?! I'm so lost, I didn't"t find anything about that on the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNp4P.png)Internet.

Comment: What's the error? I can't find it on the image, maybe you could paste the error on the question

Comment: This is the error : 

? Starter template: tabs
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\System32\Phlyn'
/ Preparing directory .\Phlyn

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is the name of the application, try to run directly:

```
ionic start phlyn
```

and then just choose the Angular framework and the type of template you want to use

references: https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cli

Comment: Even better: `ionic start myApp myAppTemplate --type=angular`

Comment: Yes but when I choose the template. For example I chose "tabs" but it put me :

Comment: Here is the error : Let's pick the perfect starter template!

Starter templates are ready-to-go Ionic apps that come packed with everything you need to build your app. To bypass thisprompt next time, supply template, the second argument to ionic start.

? Starter template: tabs
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\System32\Phlyn'
\ Preparing directory .\Phlyn

Comment: I follow the documentation but idk why I can't choose a template

Comment: wow! Wait, wait... Why do you try to init an Ionic project inside a system folder?
I think the problem is because you don't have permissions to write in that folder, try to make a folder inside a Documents or desktop folder

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot! How can I change the directory of my Ionic project ?